# Accessing controller instance variables from within an rspec controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Shouldn't I be able to see instance variables which are created in a controller action from within my rspect tests?

```
# /app/controllers/widget_controller.rb
...
def show
  @widget = ...
  puts "in controller: #{@widget}"
end
...
```

--

```
# /spec/controllers/widget_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe WidgetController, type: :controller do
...
describe "GET #show" do
  it "assigns the requested widget as @widget" do
    get :show, { :id => 1 } # this is just an example - I'm not hardcoding the id

    puts "in spec: #{@widget}"
  end
end
...
```

Here is the output I get when I run that spec:

```
controller: #<Widget:0x007f9d02aff090>
in spec:
```

Am I wrong in thinking that I should have access to @widget in my controller spec?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the `assigns` method *(***note**: `assigns` is now deprecated. See bottom of my answer for info)*:

```
it "assigns the @widget"
  expect(assigns(:widget)).not_to be_nil
end
```

Of course, you can inspect `widget` as you'd like, but without seeing what `@widget` is from your provided controller code, I just checked if it was `nil`

If you're wanting to `puts` the widget, like in your example, just print it with `assigns`

```
puts assigns(:widget)
```

---

**EDIT:** `assigns` is now deprecated (see: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/assigns)

If you want to continue using `assigns` you will need to install the [rails-controller-testing](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) gem.

Otherwise, you could use what *rails-controller-testing* gem uses internally: `@controller.view_assigns[]`

Comment: RuboCop complains about the usage of local variables in tests.
That being said `controller.view_assigns['var_name']` works just fine without the `@`

Answer (score 24):

**#[assigns](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/assigns) is deprecated.** Here's a solution that avoids pulling in the `rails-controller-testing` gem

Though it can be a [code smell](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950) to test instance variables in controllers, to upgrade older apps you can leverage [#instance_variable_get](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get).

Rspec example:
`expect(@controller.instance_variable_get(:@person).id).to eq(person_id)`

Answer (score 19):

In Rails 5, `assigns` has now been split out into a new `rails-controller-testing` gem.

You can either install the gem to continue using `assigns`, or you could use what the `rails-controller-testing` gem uses internally, which`@controller.view_assigns[]`.

Comment: @controller.view_assigns['widget']

Answer (score 0):

In new Rails versions with [`rails-controller-testing`](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) gem you can access to instance variables two ways:

- with `assigns[:key]` / `assigns['key']`
- with `controller.view_assigns['key']`

[As you see](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing/blob/master/lib/rails/controller/testing/test_process.rb) `assigns` is `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so you you can use both a string or symbol as key. It is formed with `regular_writer` method from the `Hash`, where all the keys with instance variables are strings, i.e. from `@controller.view_assigns`. But you can also access to `controller` inside tests

Here example

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  before do
    assign(:some_var, 10)

    get :show, params: { id: 1 }
  end

  it 'assigns the @some_var'
    expect(assigns['some_var']).to eq 10
    expect(assigns[:some_var]).to eq 10

    expect(controller.view_assigns['some_var']).to eq 10
  end
end
```